# Can we say that $a=b \implies a \equiv b \pmod{0}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm wondering if we can write $a=b$ as $a \equiv b \pmod{0}$.

Because the last congruence satisfies $b-a=0\times k$ $\implies b-a=0$.

Which is really $b=a$.

Comment: Well, you've already answered your question :)

Comment: ah, so it's right ?

Answer (score 3):

$a \equiv b$ modulo $c$ means that $a - b$ is divisible by $c$, i.e. there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $kc = (a-b)$. So if $c = 0$, $kc = 0$ for all $k$ so $a \equiv b$ modulo $0$ iff $a = b$. So yes. But it's unusual to work modulo $0$, and not very useful, as we see.

Answer (score 0):

Well the notation $a\equiv b\pmod{c}$ means that $a-b$ is divisible by $c$,clearly you can't divide by $0$ though $b-a$ can be written as an linear combination of $0$

Comment: Divisible by $0$ doesn't mean to divide, look at the definition $a|b \implies b=a\times k + 0$, so $0|b \implies b=0\times k + 0$.

Comment: Well what about $a\mid b\implies \frac{b}{a}=k,k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Definition

Comment: @Antaraz Yes that is the point there are 2 definitions,clearly if you use the first then $0\mid 0$ is correct if you use the second it's not.